# How do I add left and slide effect for this basic image slider in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#circle1").click(function(){
        $(".headlines").css('background-image', 'url(bg.png)');
    });

    $("#circle2").click(function(){
        $(".headlines").css('background-image', 'url(bg2.png)');
    });

    $("#circle3").click(function(){
        $(".headlines").css('background-image', 'url(bg3.png)');
    });
});
```

All `#circle` are clickable circles to make a basic image slide. When I click circle it works but I want it to have slide effect. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for. Currently the circles slide to the left. You need to change the `#circle` to `.headliner` accordingly in the Javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#circle1").click(function() {
    $("#circle1").css('background-image', 'url(bg.png)').toggle("slide");
  });

  $("#circle2").click(function() {
    $("#circle2").css('background-image', 'url(bg2.png)').toggle("slide");
  });

  $("#circle3").click(function() {
    $("#circle3").css('background-image', 'url(bg3.png)').toggle("slide");
  });
});
```

```css
#circle1,
#circle2,
#circle3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="circle1"></div>
<br />

<div id="circle2"></div>
<br />

<div id="circle3"></div>
```